# Cannot create AudioDevices on EC2・Spring-Boot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, audio, amazon-ec2, amazon-polly

Spring Boot:2.4.5
EC2: Amazon Linux2

I need to implement Amazon Polly on Spring Boot. The Implementation is succeeded on local machine. But, deployed on EC2, it invokes an error as follows:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
Cannot create AudioDevices
```

After some research, I found out that the following part causes this problem.

```
AdvancedPlayer player = new AdvancedPlayer(stream,javazoom.jl.player.FactoryRegistry.systemRegistry().createAudioDevice());
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: modprobe snd-aloop - Use this command to create a virtual audio device and run the application again

Comment: I did the code you suggested, but as following:    
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-aloop not found in directory /lib/modules/4.14.231-173.361.amzn2.x86_64

Comment: By changing Linux Distributor and kernel, modprobe snd-aloop gets valid. Thanks a lot, Ali!